# How to produce vertices vector using adjacent matrix in graph theory?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, matrix-equations

In graph theory, Let $A$ be adjacent matrix, a vector $v$ can be represented by numbers on each vertices. $v_i$ denotes the number(or label) of node $i$.

Now I want this vector $u$, such that $u_i$ counts the numbers neighbors $j$ of node $i$  who satisfies $v_j \geq v_i$, i.e. $u_i=| \{\;j:A_{ij}=1 \wedge v_j \geq v_i \; \}|$.

Using $A$ and $v$ and some other graph matrix(Laplacian and so on), how to get $u$ in matrix equations, pure math, not matlab commands?

Suppose this matrix operations $f(A,v)$ produce $u$, I want the solution $v$ such that $f(A,v) = v$(I want $u$ be equal to $v$). What equation should this be look like? Can I cast this into linear systems to get a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Is a map $i\mapsto v_i$ injective? If so, can we assume that it is a permutation of the set $\{1,\dots, n\}$?

Comment: Here you go: $$u_i = |\{j: \text{$A_{ij} = 1$ and $v_j \ge v_i$}\}|$$

Comment: @AlexRavsky, $A$ is not a permutation matrix, it represents a graph($A_{ij}=1$ if there is an edge $(i,j)$), $v_i$ denotes the number of node $i$. THanks

Comment: @Rahul  Yes, this is what $u_i$ looks like. But I want matrix computation to produce $u$, not this description. Like $u=Av$(just for illustration, I know $Av$ means relabel each node by sum of labels of neighbors.)

Comment: @user1721895 I am asking about the numbering $v$, not about the matrix $A$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky $v$ denote labels of each nodes, $v_i$ is label of node $i$. Labels are RANDOM NUMBERS. Hope I make this clear. Thanks very much.

Comment: So $v$ is not necessarily injective, right?

Comment: @AlexRavsky Yes, in this case ($v$=0), $u_i$ would be degree of each node $i$. Since each neighbor $j$ of $i$ has $v_j \geq v_i$. I want a matrix computation formular to produce $u$. There is no constraint what number in $v$.THanks.

Comment: Is the following straightforward answer OK for you? “First we need somehow represent the order of $v_i$. For this purpose we introduce a matrix $T=\|t_{ij}\|$, such that $t_{ij}=1$ if $v_j\ge v_i$ and $t_{ij}=0$, otherwise. Then $u_i$ is $i$-th diagonal element of the matrix $TA$”.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Thanks. I have got your point. The problem is following: let your representation is $f(A,v)$ since your $TA$ if built from $A$ and $v$. Now I am search for solution $v$ of this equation $f(A,v)=v$, this, in your case, $TA=v$(I want the produced $u$ be equal to $v$). What should $f$ look like..Note that $A$ is known, $v$ is unknown. THanks.

Comment: So you are asking about something like integer linear programming formulation for $v$?

Comment: @AlexRavsky Yes, I need to formulate into an linear equation(though I dont know whether this problem is linear). But I think it is not integer linear programming, since I am not optimizing it... THanks